# How to use two applications simultaneously, using mouse on one and keyboard on another?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, input-device, multitasking

Okay this may be too much effort for a thing which is not that effective, but while using dual monitors I want to play be able to type in one application, while clicking and navigating a browser simultaneously.
Screen 1 -> game which uses only keyboard
Screen 2 -> browsing
Is this possible on Windows 10?
( or some Linux distro?)

Comment: Window focus is not based on the number of monitors. If this were possible, it would be possible with only a single monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. I simulated this with Virtual Machines. I started Notepad in my host, left my mouse in this Kali Window, then used the keyboard to bring up the Host Notepad window. All worked to that point, but then the mouse clearly came with me to Notepad.

VMware simulates this because there are two different machines. But it is done with one single monitor and the mouse still goes with the keyboard. You can see this happen on screen.

So I really do not think this will work.